# Quicksort With a Comparator

Tags: java, arrays, sorting

i'am working on project to Sort an array of Student objects with the following critiria:

1.Sort grades

2.If grades are equal, sort on StudentNumber.

now i got this working using the Arrays.Sort(T[] a, Comparator<> c ) method.
since i think this sorting method is to slow, i want to use Quicksort.

i got the following piece of code:

```
public static void quickSort(Student[] arr, int low, int high) {
    if (arr == null || arr.length == 0) {
        return;
    }
    if (low >= high) {
        return;
    }
    // pick the pivot
    int middle = low + (high - low) / 2;
    Student pivot = arr[middle];
    // make left < pivot and right > pivot
    int i = low, j = high;
    while (i <= j) {
        while (arr[i].getCijfer() < pivot.getCijfer()) {
            i++;
        }
        while (arr[j].getCijfer() > pivot.getCijfer()) {
            j--;
        }
        if (i <= j) {
            Student temp = arr[i];
            arr[i] = arr[j];
            arr[j] = temp;
            i++;
            j--;
        }
    }
    // recursively sort two sub parts
    if (low < j) {
        quickSort(arr, low, j);
    }
    if (high > i) {
        quickSort(arr, i, high);
    }
}
```

UPDATE Comparator Code:

```
private static Comparator<Student> gradeComparator = new Comparator<Student>() {
    @Override
    public int compare(Student o1, Student o2) {
        int compareTo = 0;
        if (o1.cijfer > o2.cijfer) {
            compareTo = -1;
        } else {
            if (o1.cijfer < o2.cijfer) {
                compareTo = 1;
            } else {
                // als Studenten Grade gelijk, vergelijk op studenten Ldap
                if (o1.cijfer == o2.cijfer) {
                    if (o1.studentnummer > o2.studentnummer) {
                        compareTo = -1;
                    } else {
                        compareTo = 1;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return compareTo;
    }
};
```

this sorts the array on the Grades(cijfer) but i'am stuck on where to put my 2nd sorting criteria. please help me!

Kind regards

Comment: "since i think this sorting method is to slow" How slow is slow? How fast do you think it should be? I would say it's only slow if a) you are sorting *loads* of data; b) your comparator does a lot of work to compare elements. Can you post your comparator code?

Answer (score 3):

This expression: `arr[i].getCijfer() < pivot.getCijfer()` and this: `arr[j].getCijfer() > pivot.getCijfer()` are the source of your problem.  You need to extract these into a single function which returns an integer, implemented as follows: `return Integer.compare( a.getCijfer(), b..getCijfer() );`.

But then you will notice that this is just a comparator function, so you can go ahead and modify it to work exactly as it worked when you were using `Arrays.sort()` with comparator.

This addresses your question.

However, be aware of the following:

1. Your suspicion that `Arrays.sort()` will be slower than some quicksort is completely unfounded, and most likely false.
2. Your belief that you can do a home-brewed quicksort that will perform better than `Arrays.sort()` is most likely false.
3. If you do not know how to get your home-brewed quicksort to sort the way you want it to, and you have to ask on stackoverflow, there is nothing wrong with that, but then obviously, sorting is a topic which is far more advanced than what your professor expects from you.

Comment: The [Timsort algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Timsort#Performance) used by `Arrays.sort` is actually faster than quicksort in the best-case, and equally performant otherwise. Like Mike suggests, this sounds like premature optimization to me. Unless you have *millions* of students to sort, I doubt you'll have a measurable performance difference between the built-in `sort` and your custom sort.

Comment: Okay, i have assumed wrong is was quicker, but how can i add the second sort criterium

Comment: Handing out actual code that solves students assignments is generally frowned upon here.  I wrote the general idea, I think it should be enough for you to figure out how to flesh in the details.  If you don't know what to do with that information, and if that information does not help you to actually learn how to do the assignment, then you should probably fail the assignment!  Were you telling the truth when you were saying "i got this working using the Arrays.Sort(T[] a, Comparator<> c ) method"? If yes, then you know what to do.

Answer (score 0):

You would need to put your second criterion anywhere you compare two `Student` instances, e.g.

```
if (arr[i].getCijfer() < pivot.getCijfer()
    || (arr[i].getCijfer() == pivot.getCijfer()
        && arr[i].getStudentNumber() < pivot.getStudentNumber()))
```

However, it is inconvenient to add multiple criteria here, so you would be better introducing a method in which the comparison is done:

```
if (compare(arr[i], pivot) < 0)
```

and then pushing the comparison logic into that method, so that it returns some number depending upon whether `arr[i]` is less than, equal to, or greater than `pivot`.

Note that this is basically what `Comparator` provides:

```
class MyComparator implements Comparator<Student> {
  @Override int compare(Student a, Student b) {
    if (a.getCijfer() != b.getCijfer()) {
      return // Some comparison of a.getCijfer() and b.getCijfer()
    }
    // Somehow compare student number.
  }
}
```